# Linking tables using sum grouped by date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables similar to shown below. Table 1 contains a list of individual hours worked on a product and the date they are worked on. They are ordered by ID which is applied in the order the hours were entered into the database.  Table 2 contains a list that groups the hours into a record relating to the day in which the hours were approved, which is not always the day in which they were originally worked.  As shown in the goal, I want to be able to link the two tables together, and they only way I can think of how to do it is to link the name and sumOfHRS from table 1 to table 2, however, I'm not sure how I can group the data to get the desired result.  I would greatly appreciate any help with this task, because I'm still not sure how I would go about this.

```
Table 1:
ID  Name  Date   HRS
1   a     7/14   1
2   a     7/14   4
3   a     7/14   2
4   a     7/14   4
5   a     7/15   5


Table 2:
Name HRS_TOT APPROVE_DATE
a    7       7/14
a    9       7/15

Goal:
Name  HRS_TOT  APPROVE_DATE  HRS  Date
a     7        7/14          1    7/14
a     7        7/14          4    7/14
a     7        7/14          2    7/14
a     9        7/15          4    7/14
a     9        7/15          5    7/15
```

The best I've managed to do is as follows:

```
    Select t2.Name, t2.HRS_TOT, t2.APPROVE_DATE, t1.Date, t1.HRS 
   FROM t1 
   INNER JOIN t2 On t1.SumOfHRS = t2.HRS_TOT 
        t1 = SELECT Name, Date, Sum(HRS) As SumOfHRS, 
   FROM tbl1 GROUP BY date ORDER BY ID
```

But the problem is that I can't figure out how to group table1 by the approve date on table2

My only other idea is that because the HRS are in order by the ID, if there could be a running sum up until HRS_TOT is reached, then it could be grouped that way:  ie: 1 + 4 + 2 = 7, so group those with record 1 of table 2, then 4 + 5 = 9, which is the total for record 2 of table 2.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Let us see your efforts

Comment: In your Table 1 example, I think you ID 4 has a Date of 7/14 when, for your example, you want 7/15

Comment: @KyleBecker, that's why I've been having difficulty, as the Date and the Approve_Date do not have to be the same, so I can't just group table1 by date. So the table shown above is correct to how the data appears.

Comment: @scaisEdge The best I've managed to do is as follows:  `Select t2.Name, t2.HRS_TOT, t2.APPROVE_DATE, t1.Date, t1.HRS
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 On t1.SumOfHRS = t2.HRS_TOT`

`t1 = 
SELECT Name, Date, Sum(HRS) As SumOfHRS,
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY ID`   But the problem is that I can't figure out how to group table1 by the approve date on table2

Comment: I would say, this is not possible in a query, because there is no way to tell, that _ID 4_ belongs to _ID 5_.

Comment: any chance these have timestamps and not dates?

Comment: @Hogan Unfortunately, I don't have control of the format for this data, so I only have the date.

Comment: @DanF -- you do see the problem?  There is no way to know that ID 4 in the first table is not part of the other 7/14 and that it should go with ID 5 on date 7/15.  The problem is it has the same date.  You can come up with an algorithm to add up values less than or equal to approval to figure it out -- but this is not a very SQL task.  You would want C# or PHP or something to do that.

Comment: @Hogan Thank you for your help.  I do see the problem, but I wasn't sure if there could be any kind of workaround. The main reason I asked was because I wasn't sure if it was possible in SQL or not, so I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Options I see are 1. save ID from table2 into field of table1 or 2. algorithm and maybe writing records to a 'temp' table that is populated only for report output process.

Comment: @DanF -- you might be able to do it with a recursive CTE but I don't think Access supports that.